# can my eclipse rcp and plugins be used by other parties?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

If I develop my application using eclipse RCP and my own eclipse plugins, can other people copy and paste my plugins and used in other application?

thanks

Comment: Other applications other than Eclipse?

Comment: Other applications may be eclipse IDE, other eclipse plugins, or other eclipse RCP applications. oh, how about other applications other than eclipse? thanks

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is "yes". RCP applications rely on reusable plugins.

The correct answer is "it depends". It depends on what extensions and extension points you define. Basically, plugins need to "*talk*" to each other in order to work with each other. When you create a plugin, you define **who** can talk to it and **how**.

I recommend the following lecture: http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseExtensionPoint/article.html